# Opening outlook with attached pdf document in php file coding

Tags: php, html, email, mailto

window.location.href = "mailto:test@example.com?subject=Email%20Subject&body=Email%20Body&attach=example.pdf"

My Outlook mail does open when I run the code but the pdf does not attach, the pdf is saved correctly in my folder and I have tried to locate it through example.pdf and file:///C:example/example/example.pdf

Any solution to this?

window.location.href = "mailto:test@example.com?subject=Email%20Subject&body=Email%20Body&attach=example.pdf"

window.location.href = "mailto:test@example.com?subject=Email%20Subject&body=Email%20Body&attach=file:///C:example/example/example.pdf"

Comment: okay, so it's not possible to attach a pdf document in that sense correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is a security risk, because it's the website controlling what is attached, and not the user of the computer. It's also difficult to use because, under normal circumstances, the website cannot see the files that are present on the computer of the user.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this? Opening outlook application and attach pdf document, coded in .php

Comment: No there isn't. That's literally exactly what you were told already. The solution would be to use server-side code to send the email, if you need to automate it

Comment: Okay, thank you